# Android, setting alarm sound volume not working

Tags: android

I am trying to set alarm volume using  this:

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, OneValue, 0);
```

It works in Android 4.1. The Alarm sliders moves acording to my values.
But it does not work in GibgerBread. Nothing happens. I mean, I don't get to modify the volume. 
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

then override onKeyDown method and write as below :-

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

        am.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

            break;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            am.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four kind of sound setting in android 1)Alarm 2)Music 3)Ring Tone 4)Notification First Create object of AudioManager amanager; IF you want to set Volume use this code

For Notification

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Alerm

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Music

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Ring Tone

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Look in the [AudioManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) and try either of this

Comment: One thing with these examples - you combine flags with '|', rather than with '+'